# How to solve a nonlinear second order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have been trying to find ways to solve:
$$J\frac{d²\theta(t)}{dt²}-K_m cos(\theta(t))=-\tau_f$$
With the initial conditions 
$$\theta(t=0)=0$$
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}(t=0)=0$$
Without success. Is that this complicated?

Which should lead to theta(t) = a step to pi/2 with damped oscillations.

Comment: isn't it a pendulum equation which can be integrated with elliptic functions ?

Have a look at the Lawden's book p.114 that you can download here

http://gen.lib.rus.ec/search.php?req=lawden+elliptic&open=0&res=25&view=simple&phrase=1&column=def

Comment: If you are interested in finding approximate solutions that are in terms of elementary functions then you can linearise the equation about about a small angle.

Answer (score 1):

$$J\frac{d²\theta(t)}{dt²}-K_m \cos(\theta(t))=-\tau_f$$
$$2J\frac{d²\theta(t)}{dt²} \frac{d\theta(t)}{dt} -2K_m \cos(\theta(t))\frac{d\theta(t)}{dt}=-2\tau_f\frac{d\theta(t)}{dt}$$

$$J\left(\frac{d\theta(t)}{dt} \right)^2 -2K_m \sin(\theta(t)) =-2\tau_f \theta(t) +c_1$$

Condition : $t=0\quad \theta=0\quad\frac{d\theta(t)}{dt}=0 \quad\to\quad c_1=0$

$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}= \pm \sqrt{J\left(2K_m \sin(\theta) -2\tau_f \theta \right) }$$

$$t=\pm \int_{x=0}^{x=\theta} \frac {dx}{\sqrt{J\left(2K_m \sin(x) -2\tau_f \: x \right) }}$$

There is no closed form for this integral (this isn't an elliptic integral)